# NA-recognizing boolean operator

Tags: r, boolean, na

Is there a boolean opperator that gives me `NA` if any of the parts is `NA`?
Currently

```
NA & FALSE == FALSE
FALSE & NA == FALSE
NA & TRUE  == NA
TRUE & NA  == NA
```

I'd like to have:

```
NA x FALSE == NA
FALSE x NA == NA
```

PS:

I'm searching for an operator x for which

```
  x     |  a=TRUE  |  =FALSE | =NA
-----------------------------------
b=TRUE  |    TRUE  |   FALSE |  NA
 =FALSE |    FALSE |   FALSE |  NA
 =NA    |    NA    |   NA    |  NA
```

so I could do

```
result <- a x b
```

Comment: It would be helpful to put this in actual R syntax, so it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: you could try `any`... `xx <- c(1,2,3,NA,4,5); any(is.na(xx))`

Comment: @Arun `any` is an extension of `|` and `|` actually works the way Hoffmann wants.  The extension of `&` is `all` and it has the same issue

Comment: @Dason, right on. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define your own operator that does what you want.

```
> `%and%` <- function(x, y){as.logical(x*y)}
> NA %and% FALSE
[1] NA
> FALSE %and% NA
[1] NA
> NA %and% TRUE
[1] NA
> TRUE %and% NA
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 6):

Dason's approach is cool, but if want something more readable by mortals, use this:

```
`%&%` <- function(e1, e2) ifelse(is.na(e1)|is.na(e2), NA, e1 & e2)
```

Results:

```
> x <- c(TRUE, FALSE, NA)
> outer(x, x, `%&%`)
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE   NA
[2,] FALSE FALSE   NA
[3,]    NA    NA   NA
```

EDIT: Benchmarking:

It should be noted that Dason's approach is the fastest, as shown below:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(compiler)

x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), size=1e3, TRUE)
y <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), size=1e3, TRUE)

`%&1%` <- function(e1, e2) ifelse(is.na(e1)|is.na(e2), NA, e1 & e2)
`%&2%` <- function(x, y) (!x | y) & (x | y) & (x | !y)
`%and%` <- function(x, y)as.logical(x*y)
```

Note: `%&2%` is a funny alternative I've just found by luck :-)

Let's compile all this to see what happen:

```
`%C&2%` <- cmpfun(`%&2%`)
`%C&1%` <- cmpfun(`%&1%`)
`%Cand%` <- cmpfun(`%and%`)

> microbenchmark(x %&1% y, x %&2% y, x %and% y, x %C&1% y, x %C&2% y, x %Cand% y, times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
       expr     min      lq  median      uq      max neval
   x %&1% y 201.575 206.124 208.574 211.024 1822.917  1000
   x %&2% y  86.439  87.140  87.839  88.190 1244.441  1000
  x %and% y  13.299  13.999  14.349  14.700 1141.905  1000
  x %C&1% y 200.525 205.775 208.574 210.674 1554.151  1000
  x %C&2% y  84.690  85.390  86.090  86.440 1212.596  1000
 x %Cand% y  13.299  13.649  14.349  14.699 1141.555  1000
```

Funny, compiler doesn't changes anything here!

Comment: Sure! My main suggestion was just that we could build our own operator since I don't think there is one built in that does what we want.  The boolean algebra in my answer shouldn't be too bad to follow though and at any rate it's easy enough to build the truth table (like you did) to see that it gives the desired answer.  Nice alternative though!